# Can iOS App Manage Multiple Auto-Renewable Subscriptions?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, subscriptions, auto-renewable

We'd like to support in our app several distinct auto-renewable subscriptions. For example, subscribe to feature A for a year, feature b for a year, feature c for a year.
We want the subscriptions to be separate and allow users to subscribe to one or more of these without offering an A + B, or A + C option.

Is this possible? All tutorials I've seen talk about a single subscription type with different durations.